# $http post and event handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to broadcast an event between the http request processing and success response but till now I am not able to figure out the solution:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:fileTransferInProgress');
$http.post("/api/example", data, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}                   
           }).success(function(response){
               $rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:readyState', response);

          }).error(function(){
              $rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:error');
          });
```

I want to trigger the ('transfer:fileTransferInProgress') event between the success and request processing. How I could do this??

Comment: please provide the code where you catch event

Comment: Do what specifically? You are already triggering with your broadcasts. really not clear what you are asking or what is or isn't happening based on expectations

Comment: I want to make sure that post call is triggered and is in process. In the above code I am doing broadcasting of message before actual post call start. I want to trigger the event between the post call start and before the completion  of it. I hope so it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment:

```
$scope.$on(success || error event, function() {
   if(msg exists) destroy msg
   show new msg
});
```

Comment: I am already catching the event. I need below condition to satisfy: I want to make sure that post call is triggered and is in process. In the above code I am doing broadcasting of message before actual post call start. I want to trigger the event between the post call start and before the completion of it. I hope so it is clear now.

Comment: Then put the broadcast after the post call.

Comment: I tried that option but it override the previous success and failure events.

Comment: What do you mean by (previous)?

Comment: It can't override, do you mean it happened after the success or error?

Comment: I mean whatever broadcast is present after the post call, it displays only and other message disappears. I want to display the success or error message once post is completed.

Comment: 1- Broadcast doesn't override, it just broadcasts events.     2- the  
$rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:readyState', response); you mentioned is in the response so it most probably will execute after the initial $rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:fileTransferInProgress');    3- if you want to guarantee it to come after you can try putting it in a $timeout to execute in the next cycle

Comment: What you say is another issue. you can check inside the success/error event if another message is displayed remove it first and show the new one.

Comment: Okay.. let me check, i think I need to bring progress event outside of timeout.

Comment: I kept outside of $timeout and it is working fine.. Thank you for your help.